# jQuery append function is just appending the html but not the classes related to it

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I am using php laravel and so it uses blade template to render the views. Following is the javascript code to append html script :-

```
$(function () {
   var count = 0;
   $("#min_bonus_value").click(function () {
      count++;
      var min_bonus_html =
                    '<div class="min_bonus_row">' +
                        '<hr>' +
                        '<div class="row">' +
                            '<div class="col-md-2">' +
                                '<div class="form-group">' +
                                    '<label for="bonus_day[' + count + ']">@lang('admin.message759')<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>' +
                                    '<select class="select2 form-control" id="bonus_day[' + count + ']" name="bonus_day[' + count + '][]" data-placeholder="@lang('admin.message759')" multiple>' +
                                        '<option value="1">Monday</option>' +
                                        '<option value="2">Tuesday</option>' +
                                        '<option value="3">Wednesday</option>' +
                                        '<option value="4">Thursday</option>' +
                                        '<option value="5">Friday</option>' +
                                        '<option value="6">Saturday</option>' +
                                        '<option value="7">Sunday</option>' +
                                    '</select>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
```

Following is the piece of blade template code where the above html needs to be appended, I want to append 'select2' class which is styled to select multiple days, but in vain :-

```
<div id="minimum_bonus">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. What is this `<div id="minimum_bonus">` supposed to represent? The parent element where you want to append the code?

Comment: Aside from that, I'd expect `data-placeholder="@lang('admin.message759')"` to break your JS syntax, since you're using single quotes within single quotes. Is your browser's console reporting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I may be off here but when you say "not the classes", do you actually mean the Javascript/jQuery funcionality?

If so, I'll try to explain what is happening: when you initialize a jQuery plugin, like select2, it acts upon what exists in the DOM at the moment you initialize it. So if you later create new  items, these won't have the select2 functionality, unless you initialize it again for said new items.

I suggest you create a function to initialize select2 and call it whenever you add new  elements to your DOM. You'd need to somehow single out the elements that have already been initialized. You can do so with a class, in this example, the class is 'select2-enabled'. Like this:

```
function initSelect2() {
  $(".select2").each(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('select2-enabled')) {
      $(this).addClass('select2-enabled');
      $(this).select2({
        // all your select2 options
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And then, after you append your new html, you can call your function to initialize select2 on the new elements:

```
$(parentElement).append(newHTML);
initSelect2();
```